# php to htaccess rewrite - redirect if no $_POST data

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

```
if( count( $_POST ) < 1 ) {
    // determine if this was a secure request - we use a non standard HTTPS port so the SERVER_HTTPS_PORT define should always be used in place of 443
    $protocol = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == SERVER_HTTPS_PORT ? 'https' : 'http';
    header( "HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    header( "Status: 301" ); // this is for chrome compliance
    header( "Location: $protocol://".CLIENT_DOMAIN."{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}" );       
    session_write_close();
    exit;
}
```

Can this functionality be rewritten with .htaccess rules?

Logic:

If not a POST request, redirect to equivalent page with whole query string by issuing 301 header and status, whilst maintaining protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^443(s)|.*
RewriteRule ^foo/bar$ http%1://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Not you just need to replace `443` by your `SERVER_HTTPS_PORT` value and `www.example.com` by your `CLIENT_DOMAIN` value.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you (replace `www.google.com` with your `CLIENT_DOMAIN`).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.google.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lookink at the documentation of Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html), there might be a way, using `%{REQUEST_METHOD}` in a `RewriteCond` condition ; something like this might do the trick :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
```

Followed, of course, by the needed `RewriteRule` to redirect everything to the non-POST page.

I have no way of testing right now, so this might not be perfect, but something like this could maybe do the trick -- or, at least, guide you to the solution :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

The idea beeing to

- match everything
- redirect to what was matched
- keeping the Query String (QSA flag)
- and redirecting with a 301 code
- and stopping there

Comment: Your solution doesn't match server port and it redirects to the same site instead of `CLIENT_DOMAIN`.

Comment: As I said, it was not a full-solution ; more a couples of ideas that were intended to guide the OP a chance of experimenting, while he was waiting for others to help :-)